# Building a DOM tree in Java by scanning an html file

Tags: java, stack

Purpose of my build() method: To build the tree just keep reading the next line with the scanner. If it doesn't have a "/" in it push it onto the stack. When you read in a line with a "/" ..()...then you're going to keep popping from the stack until you find the matching tag without the "/" so . Everything that's popped will be connected as siblings and when you get to the final pop which is the matching tag you'll make its firstChild the last popped tag.

```
public void build() {

        Stack<String> tags = new Stack<String>();
        TagNode ptr = null;
        String tmp = null;


        if(tags.isEmpty()  == true){ // base case
            return;
        }
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){ 
            String tag = sc.nextLine();
            if(!tag.startsWith("</")){ //pushes everything that isn't a closing tag into the stack
                tags.push(tag);
            }else{ //a closing tag is found
                tag.replaceAll("/", "");
                while(!tags.peek().equals(tag)){ //now we start popping the stack in search of the opening tag
                    tmp = tags.peek();
                    tags.pop();
                    ptr = new TagNode(tmp, null, null);
                    ptr.sibling = ptr;
                }// the opening tag is found
                tmp = tags.peek();
                tags.pop();
                ptr = new TagNode(tmp, null, null);
                ptr.firstChild = ptr;
            }
        }//we're at the last element in the stack
        root = ptr.firstChild;
    }
```

Comment: you can ignore line of code marked as a "//base case"

Comment: what was your question again?

Comment: What _is_ the question, though? How can we help you?

Comment: so once I come across a closing tag, my code pops everything out of the stack instead of stopping once it reaches it's opening tag (</p to <p>)..I thought the while(!tags.peek().equals(tag) would stop it from popping everything out. My question is why is this happening?